# C#: Form.DoubleBuffered = true kills transparancy

Tags: c#, winforms, transparency

1. Create a new windows forms project
2. Set TransparancyKey & BackColor of this form to "Black"
3. Run

=> Form is shown transparent

Now also set the 
Form.DoubleBuffered property to true

=> Form isn't shown transparent anymore

Why this?
Any workarounds for getting a double buffered transparent form?

Comment: Double buffering certainly kills other ways to achieve transparency.  Just not TransparencyKey.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to worry about your TransparencyKey and BackColor properties for transparency and double buffering to work. Leave them as default and try it again. Then, if you really want your backcolor to be black, try to apply that value.

The following snippet produces a 50% transparent window on my machine:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public partial class Form1 : Form {
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        DoubleBuffered = true;
        AllowTransparency = true;
        BackColor = Color.Black;
        Opacity = .5;
    }
}
```

Comment: Opacity is no substitute for transparency.

Comment: ok so what i'm doing in detail: the form has a png image background that contains some transparent parts. This is why i use TransparencyKey and BackColor, because this makes the form transparent at the areas where the background png image is transparent. But as soon as i set DoubleBuffered = true this doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Could you post a screen cap of the working (non-double buffered) image so we can see what you're after?

Answer (score 0):

I have just tried your steps to replicate and it is working fine for me. Perhaps this is a .Net version / OS version / Graphsics issue of some kind.

For reference I am testing with...

- VS 2010
- Windows 7 (32 bit)
- .Net 4

Comment: ok so what i'm doing in detail: the form has a png image background that contains some transparent parts. This is why i use TransparencyKey and BackColor, because this makes the form transparent at the areas where the background png image is transparent. But as soon as i set DoubleBuffered = true this doesn't work anymore.     i have VS2010 Express, Win XP

Comment: @nr1, I would say the issue is to do with setting a background image then. Maybe it is worth trying to draw the image your self on the forms OnPaint event (or use a panel which fills the form, I would probably go for this option)